# Create bootstrap Pagination bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am creating a simple bootstrap pagination bar,but its displaying like this
[image]

My code here

```
        <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
            <li><a href="#"></a>&laquo;</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>1</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>2</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>3</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>4</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>&raquo;</li>
        </ul>
```

I have added fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sjfthag9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
look at your code the numbers are on the outside of the a tag

https://jsfiddle.net/sjfthag9/1/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers need to be inside the `<a></a>` tags.

See below:

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
    <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```